# CSS - Линия * по всей ширине экрана

Tags: css, frontend

Мне нужно сделать линию из * что бы адаптировалось по всей ширине экрана

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте такую линию максимально длинной (чтобы хватало для самых больших экранов), поместите её внутри блока-обёртки и задайте этому блоку `overflow: hidden`. Тогда визуально будет казаться, что она адаптируется (а на самом деле будет видна только какая-то её часть):

```css
.line-wrap {
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-wrap">
************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит как костыль, а крайняя правая звёздочка некрасиво обрезается

Comment: @andreymal, предложите свой вариант - с удовольствием поставлю плюс, если он окажется лучше моего

Comment: У меня переходит на строку ниже, скажу сразу я вообще не силен в CSS и это мне нужно для андроид что бы печатать кассовый чек(принтер понимает только HTML/CSS).
Нельзя никак сделать что бы не переходило ниже а было в одной строке?

Comment: @Andrew, можно добавить ещё `white-space: nowrap` - тогда по идее не будет переноситься (я обновил ответ)

Comment: @Danila да, это как раз то что нужно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test {
  height: 7px;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHBAMAAAA2fErgAAAAJFBMVEX///+KioowMDBAQEAMDAxiYmLm5ubMzMxQUFC2trYiIiIAAAA2IPbUAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACVJREFUCB1jYAADLiDJNaOKgYEtpIGBgcO4mYGBk4kTKMjIwAAAMvcC1AqHZy8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: А можно как тоже самое только что бы звездочка была с моего фонта и с паддингом и размером шрифта?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line-wrap {
  padding: 4px;
   background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHBAMAAAA2fErgAAAAJFBMVEX///+KioowMDBAQEAMDAxiYmLm5ubMzMxQUFC2trYiIiIAAAA2IPbUAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACVJREFUCB1jYAADLiDJNaOKgYEtpIGBgcO4mYGBk4kTKMjIwAAAMvcC1AqHZy8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');

}
```

```html
<div class="line-wrap">
</div>
```